# How to find Android-SDK in Android Studio installation path

Tags: android, qt, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I've installed Android Studio 2.2.3 to use on Qt Creator for creating Android apps.

I followed the Docs of Qt until [Setting Up the Development Environment](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html) part. At that page and under that section there is figure showing the locations of items to put there.

I've put the location of all other items (say, *jdk-8u121-windows-x64*, *android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64*) but con't fild any folder named *Android-SDK* in the Android Studio's path to locate and put its path to there. :(

How to find it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio: Go to Settings (on Windows this is Ctrl+Alt+S) then `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK` then near the top there is the Android SDK Location.

Comment: Thank you (+1). Mine is here: **C:\Users\CS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk**. Is it enough to put at that location?

Comment: That is the location of your SDK so I would assume that's the directory that Qt (not sure what that is) wants. Some tools can request the platform-tools directory inside the sdk but most likely that folder is the one it wants

Comment: Thanks. I will make your answer acceptable soon. :)